# Dynamic language switch with a link in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

How am I supposed to change language's config file value to `french` when `<a href="?language=french"...</a>` is clicked ?

I mean, on the sidebar there should be an option to change website language when you click on available `<a>` tag links.

Here is my code which render sidebar block:

```
    <h5>Change lang</h5>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(). '?language=english';?>">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(). '?language=french';?>">French</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            Current lang is: <?php echo $this->config->item('language');?>
        </p>
```

Comment: do you want to permanent change it for the site, or just for that user? You could store the 'current language' in a session, or in a database

Comment: by default it will be english, but when lang is changed, it should change just for current user, so session would be nice..one question. Why not cookies, why session ? Any perf difference ?

Comment: Sessions are safer than cookies to store user data.